# What are Philippa Foot's considerations on the trolley problem?

Tags: ethics, analytic-philosophy

The [trolley problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trolley_problem) is a thought experiment in ethics that goes like this:

> Suppose that a judge or magistrate is faced with rioters demanding
>   that a culprit be found for a certain crime and threatening otherwise
>   to take their own bloody revenge on a particular section of the
>   community. The real culprit being unknown, the judge sees himself as
>   able to prevent the bloodshed only by framing some innocent person and
>   having him executed. Beside this example is placed another in which a
>   pilot whose aeroplane is about to crash is deciding whether to steer
>   from a more to a less inhabited area. To make the parallel as close as
>   possible it may rather be supposed that he is the driver of a runaway
>   tram which he can only steer from one narrow track on to another; five
>   men are working on one track and one man on the other; anyone on the
>   track he enters is bound to be killed. In the case of the riots the
>   mob have five hostages, so that in both the exchange is supposed to be
>   one man's life for the lives of five.

I know that **Philippa Foot** formulated the (in)famous trolley problem, but I never heard of her own opinion regarding it. Did she ever express her opinion on this? If so, what was her position?

Answer (score 6):

Phillipa Foot discussed the trolley problem in her article, "The Problem of Abortion and the Doctrine of the Double Effect," which originally appeared in the *Oxford Review*, Number 5, 1967.

A copy of this article is [free on line](http://www2.econ.iastate.edu/classes/econ362/hallam/readings/footdoubleeffect.pdf). The extract that you posted was originally from that article. What I have copied below is how the article continues after your extract.

> The question is why we should say, without hesitation, that the driver
>   should steer for the less occupied track, while most of us would be
>   appalled at the idea that the innocent man could be framed. It may be
>   suggested that the special feature of the latter case is that it
>   involves the corruption of justice, and this is, of course, very
>   important indeed. But if we remove that special feature, supposing
>   that some private individual is to kill an innocent person and pass
>   him off as the criminal we still find ourselves horrified by the idea.
>   The doctrine of double effect offers us a way out of the difficulty,
>   insisting that it is one thing to steer towards someone foreseeing
>   that you will kill him and another to aim at his death as part of your
>   plan. Moreover there is one very important element of good in what is
>   here insisted. In real life it would hardly ever be certain that the
>   man on the narrow track would be killed. Perhaps he might find a
>   foothold on the side of the tunnel and cling on as the vehicle hurtled
>   by. The driver of the tram does not then leap off and brain him with a
>   crowbar. The judge, however, needs the death of the innocent man for
>   his (good) purposes.

I Trust this assists. A number of people have subsequently considered the Trolley Problem, notably Judith Jarvis Thomson who developed  many intriguing variants to the problem.